# Python regex not matching images on website (it matches in regex helper)

Tags: python, html, regex

I do not understand what is wrong with my script below.

It is supposed to parse out images using regex. I've verified that my regex is correct by using http://regex101.com/.

The problem is it doesn't even grab the first image on the website (even it should?).

**The website in the script is a NSFW blog. Please don't go to the link if you are offended by nudity or sexuality.**

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re

base = "http://bassrx.tumblr.com"
url = "http://bassrx.tumblr.com/tagged/tt"

def parse_page(url):
# returns html for parsing
    page = urlopen(url)
    html = page.read()
    return html

def get_links(html):
# returns list of all image urls on page
    jpgs = re.findall("src.\"(.*?500.jpg)", html, re.IGNORECASE)
    #pngs = re.findall("src.\"(.*?media.tumblr.*?tumblr_.*?png)", html, re.IGNORECASE)
    #links = jpgs + pngs
    return jpgs


html = parse_page(url)      # get the html for first page
links = get_links(html)     # get all relevant image links
print links
```

The very first image has the following HTML:

```
src="http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9q9feJcxl1qi02clo3_500.jpg" alt="">
```

I would like to know why it doesn't grab this image (and also misses most of the others).

Comment: Works fine. ['http://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ln5gwxHYei1qi02clo1_500.jpg', 'http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lnmh4tD3sM1qi02clo1_500.jpg', 'http://38.media.tumblr.com/c84fce183b6220eba854ce8933a13110/tumblr_n3lxgtqp7K1qi02clo1_500.jpg']

Comment: Maybe server knows you too well and treats you as spamer/hacker and sends you page without images.

Comment: @user8708 it doesn't work. it will not grab the first image: tumblr_m9q9feJcxl1qi02clo3_500.jpg ??

Comment: @furas it appears to send me all of the html, so i don't think it is the case.

Comment: @Daniel How did you test it? By running the actual script? As it isn't working for me still..

Comment: @user2071506 are images in that html you get ? Print it in console and check it.

Comment: `re.findall("src.\"(.*?500.jpg)", "<img src=\"<link_from_above>_500.jpg\" alt=\"\">", re.IGNORECASE)` returns the desired list. Your problem is most likely **not** the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [BeautifulSoup](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to do this..

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re

>>> page = urlopen('http://bassrx.tumblr.com/tagged/tt')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
>>> [x['src'] for x in soup.find_all('img',{'src':re.compile('500\.jpg$')})]
```

Output

```
[
  u'http://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ln5gwxHYei1qi02clo1_500.jpg',
  u'http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lnmh4tD3sM1qi02clo1_500.jpg',
  u'http://38.media.tumblr.com/c84fce183b6220eba854ce8933a13110/tumblr_n3lxgtqp7K1qi02clo1_500.jpg'
]
```

If you want the entire image tag, use the following:

```
>>> soup.find_all('img',{'src':re.compile('500\.jpg$')})
```